# If / Else jQuery to skip undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this chained select box ([demo](http://painfulmouth.com/index2.php)) using JSON file to populate options based on [this script](http://koviko.net/tutorial/building-an-accessible-client-side-chained-selection-drop-down).

Here's the script:

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {
   $.getJSON('suggest.json', function(data){
        var $select = $('#mySelectID');

        $.each(data, function (index, o) {
            var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.Box1ID + ":" + o.Box3).text(o.Box1 + "|" + o.Box2 + "|" + o.Box3);
            $select.append($option);
        });

        $("#mySelectID").dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":"|"});
    });
});
```

I have trouble using `if` statement to skip undefined value. The JSON file is like this:

```
[{"Box1":"A","Box1ID":"B","Box3":"C"},{"Box1":"E","Box1ID":"F","Box2":"G","Box3":"H"}]
```

If `Box2` doesn't exist, I want the `var $option` to be:

```
var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.Box1ID + ":" + o.Box3).text(o.Box1 + "|" + o.Box3);
```

Would  `typeof undefined`  work here?  But I'm not sure what variable should be defined.

```
if (typeof var?? === 'undefined') {
    var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.Box1ID + ":" + o.Box3).text(o.Box1 + "|" + o.Box3); } 
else {
    $("<option/>").attr("value", o.Box1ID + ":" + o.Box3).text(o.Box1 + "|" + o.Box2 + "|" + o.Box3);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
   ... .text(o.Box1 + "|" + (o.Box2?oBox2+"|":"")  +  (o.Box3||"") );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just do this:

```
if (! data.Box2) {
    ...
}
```

Undefined, null, and empty string all test as false in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {
   $.getJSON('suggest.json', function(data){
        var $select = $('#mySelectID');

        $.each(data, function (index, o) {
            var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.Box1ID + ":" + o.Box3);
            if (typeof data.Box2 === 'undefined')
            {
                $option.text(o.Box1 + "|"  + o.Box3);

            }
            else {
                $option.text(o.Box1 + "|" + o.Box2 + "|" + o.Box3);
            }

            $select.append($option);
        });

        $("#mySelectID").dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":"|"});
    });
});
```

If you check the typeof of a object method/attribute that does not exists, it will return 'undefined'.